# Task Scheduler Settings in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, scheduled-tasks

What does the checkbox in the following screenshot do?

[image]

From Microsoft:

> If task fails, restart every:
>
> Use this setting to restart a task if the task fails to run (the last
>   run result of the task is not a success). You specify the time
>   interval that takes place between task restart attempts, and the
>   number of times to try to restart the task.

I assume from this if the program doesn't return the success code (Zero; 0) then the scheduled program will be restarted with given time period?

Answer (score 0):

That would be correct.  I imagine one scenario of needing this would be if you have a VPN connection that takes a second to fully load and you're trying to open a file from a network drive.  Usually the scheduled task would fire before the VPN connection is established, and it would fail.  Using this would allow the network file to be retried automatically.  Very useful in some instances where VPN takes a long time to connect (such as my work).